# Can delay pedals output the delayed audio without any additional effects?

Tags: delay

Can standard delay pedals be configured in such a way that all they do is buffer the input signal and output it delayed, but otherwise unchanged, i.e. without adding any effects like reverb/echo?

**Background:**
I need to delay an audio signal coming from a microphone going into a computer's soundcard by up to 2 seconds. I only want the delay, I don't want to add any effects to the signal. Also, this must work with closed-source software, e.g. Skype. I didn't find any transparent software solution, but I came across delay pedals as a potential hardware-based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, pretty much any delay - hardware or software - can do this. Delay devices have a 'feedback' setting which you would want to turn to zero, and a wet / dry setting which you would want to turn to 100% wet.